# Need help to understand this code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem to understand this code

```
def get_device_sensors(device_id):
    return [elm["sensor"] for elm in db.DB.query("select * from data ",
                                                 (device_id,))]
```

I'm new in python. I don't know what does `elm["sensor"]` mean.
Does it mean?:

```
for elm in db.DB.query("select * from data ")
    return elm['sensor']
```

Comment: It is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means exactly the same as:

```
results = []
for elem in db.DB.query("SELECT * FROM data", (device_id,)):
    results.append(elem['sensor'])

return results
```

This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like @khelwood noted, which means you are constructing a list from something you can iterate over.

To summarise:

```
[ <operation> for <values> in <iterable> ]
```

basically is a shorthand for:

```
accumulator = []
for <values> in <iterable>:
     accumulator.append(<operation>)
# accumulator contains the result now.
```

`<operation>` usually does something with `<values>`, but it may also be a constant or just the `<values>` itself.

Comment: Maybe you purposely omitted this, but list comprehensions also optionally have a condition at the end. `[ <operation> for <values> in <iterable> if <condition> ]` or something like that to follow your presentation.

Comment: Yeah, but I left that up to the python documentation. No need to start reproducing all of it here... It also explains in a much better way how to use multiple `for` segments.